# Variable in ExpressJS not defined on Same-View Form

Tags: express, ejs

I am facing a problem where a variable in Express/EJS is not defined and therefore the view doesn't load.
Here I want to display a variable called weather on the page if defined. Instead I get the error "weather is not defined". I have also tried 'null'. This, by the way, is at the beginning. Because, when I submit the form, the weather-variable would be defined by the value from the input. So the evening over I tried around with no success. Is there a better approach or do I have a mistake in the way I want to get it done?

The following shows the code (I assume the problem is more about Express/EJS rather than Node):

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body style="background-color:gray; color:black;">
    <h1>
      Hello World
    </h1>
    <form action="/form" method="post">
        <label for="team_name">Enter name: </label>
        <input id="team_name" type="text" name="name_field" value="Default name for team.">
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>

  <% if(weather !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%= weather %></p>
  <% } %>

  <% if(error !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%= error %></p>
  <% } %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using "locals". This is what the code looks like. I'll edit the answer asap and explain why locals are the reason it works.

```
  <% if(locals.weather !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%= locals.weather %></p>
  <% } %>

  <% if(locals.error !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%= locals.error %></p>
  <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That will work fine if you use `typeof`

```
<% if(typeof weather !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%= weather %></p>
  <% } %>

  <% if(typeof error !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%= error %></p>
  <% } %>
```